# Rewrite all requests to index.php with nginx

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

In my apache configuration I have the following simple rewrite rule which

1. unless file exists will rewrite to index.php
2. on the urls you never see the file extension (.php)

how can I rewrite this in nginx?

```
#
# Redirect all to index.php
#
RewriteEngine On

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/[^.]*|\.)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Here's how my nginx server block looks like now, but it doesn't work :(

```
root /home/user/www;
index index.php;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name some-domain.dev;


###############################################################
# exclude /favicon.ico from logs
location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}   

##############################################################
# Disable logging for robots.txt
location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}   

##############################################################
# Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as 
# .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}   

##############################################################
#   
location / { 
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/index.php$args;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
}   

###############################################################
# serve static files directly
location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires    30d;
}   

###############################################################
# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root html;
}   

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#   
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    # With php5-cgi alone:
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**1 unless file exists will rewrite to index.php**

Add the following to your `location ~ \.php$`

```
try_files = $uri @missing;
```

this will first try to serve the file and if it's not found it will move to the `@missing` part. so also add the following to your config (outside the `location` block), this will redirect to your index page

```
location @missing {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$host/index.php permanent;
}
```

---

**2 on the urls you never see the file extension (.php)**

to remove the php extension read the following:
http://www.nullis.net/weblog/2011/05/nginx-rewrite-remove-file-extension/

and the example configuration from the link:

```
location / {
    set $page_to_view "/index.php";
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
    root   /var/www/site;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/site$page_to_view;
}

# rewrites
location @rewrites {
    if ($uri ~* ^/([a-z]+)$) {
        set $page_to_view "/$1.php";
        rewrite ^/([a-z]+)$ /$1.php last;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't really work. I get an empty response from nginx. In error log it reports the following

2012/10/17 15:23:14 [alert] 17437#0: worker process 17440 exited on signal 11 (core dumped)

Comment: the combination of the two configs probably messes things up when you combine them like this, do they work when you only try one at a time?

Comment: can u tell me the configuration for nested levels also. this configuration works well on first level routes

Comment: This method is less versatile than the higher rated answers here. Particularly you'll get into problems using this method behind a reverse proxy where the url will be rewritten to the local hostname and not the public one.

Comment: What does `=` do in `try_files =` line? and what does `^` do in `rewrite ^` line?

Comment: `$scheme://$host/` will remove the port from url which is not desired

Answer (score 143):

I have tried this and succeeded to get my index page.
When I have added this code in my site configuration file:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

Inside the configuration file itself it is explained that these are the configured steps

> First attempt to serve request as file,
> then as directory,
> then fall back to index.html

In my case it is `index.php`, as I am providing page through php code.

Comment: Wow, that is way too easy.

Comment: This works but get variables aren't passed correctly anymore. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: @Ben I believe this will do the trick: try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

Comment: You're my hero!

Comment: @Ben try: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;`

Comment: @Ben it just works for most urls, not all. if you go to the url /r9eijguhnbhher.php  (or *ANYTHING* that ends with `.php` ) it doesn't work. ***this works for all urls that does not end with `.php`***

Comment: **Warning: this only works for urls that does not end with `.php` , for example it doesn't work with `/example.php` , example.php here will NOT be redirected to index.php**

Answer (score 67):

To pass get variables as well use `$args`:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Comment: **Warning: this only works for urls that does not end with .php , for example it doesn't work with `/example.php` , example.php will NOT be redirected to index.php**

Answer (score 19):

Flat and simple config without rewrite, can work in some cases:

```
location / {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/webuser/site/index.php;
}
```

Comment: Good one! Just what I looking for, works for me and I think that it's an optimum solution, faster than rewriting.

Comment: @Lix I agree, this is a better solution. If it needed anything else at all it would be worth the effort on overhead. 

iutinvg, +1 for fast static route.

Comment: The Nginx documentation advises against proxying all calls to PHP: http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Proxy_Everything

Comment: NGINX advises against only in the case that you have static content to serve as well. If this is not your case, I believe this is the best solution.

Answer (score 11):

Using nginx $is_args instead of ? For GET query Strings

```
location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args; }
```

Comment: **Warning: this only works for urls that does not end with .php , for example it doesn't work with `/example.php` , example.php here will NOT be redirected to index.php **

Answer (score 5):

Here's the answer of your 2nd question :

```
   location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1.php last;
}
```

it's work for me (based my experience), means that all of your blabla.php will rewrite into blabla

like http://yourwebsite.com/index.php to http://yourwebsite.com/index

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me to solve part 1 of this question:

```
    location / {
            rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }
```

**rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;** rewrites non-file addresses (addresses without file extensions) to have a "/" at the end. I did this because I was running into "Access denied." message when I tried to access the folder without it.

**try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php =404;** is borrowed from SanjuD's answer, but with an extra 404 reroute if the location still isn't found.

**fastcgi_index index.php;** was the final piece of the puzzle that I was missing. The folder didn't reroute to the index.php without this line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass just the index.php ( no other php file will be passed to fastcgi ) to fastcgi in case you have routes like this in a framework like codeigniter

```
$route["/download.php"] = "controller/method";


location ~ index\.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi.conf;
}
```