# PHP - Create new URL's with file

Tags: php, hyperlink, directory, content-management-system, system

I making a little CMS, but I dont like these links, for example, `example.com/page.php`. I want to make a something like this `example.com/page` with the same file. I know I can make a new directory and put a index.php file, but, if I have 20 pages, then I need new 20 directories, and that's not a solution.

Comment: What you are searching for is called a router, there is a lot of implementations in all frameworks, yu can do it with plain php, use this http://php.net/manual/fr/class.yaf-router.php for instance, but you can also search for php routers, a thousand of implementations are available on the internet

Comment: @D.Peter Thank you, but I don't know, how to use it, can you please help me?

Comment: It depends on your webserver, wich one are you using ? apache, nginx, lighttpd, another ?

Comment: @D.Peter Im using nginx

Comment: you have to rewrite your routes, such as here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924896/rewrite-all-requests-to-index-php-with-nginx routes are in the nginx_dir/conf/nginx.conf but if it is too complicated, and if you don't want a dependance of the server, You can use a framework such as Silex or Sympony, or whatever, wich are providing a routing easiest with teh possibility to change you backend server easily. you can however use a simple router such as  https://github.com/dannyvankooten/PHP-Router (take a look at Yaml router on at the end of the page)

Answer (score 0):

I found a answer for my problem
In *.htaccess* file need to add `RewriteRule`

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^page$ /page.php [L]
RewriteRule ^page2$ /page2.php [L]
```