# php8.2-fpm not rendering with nginx

Tags: php, nginx, fpm

I was trying to set up ngninx to accept files without `.php` extension but php-fpm (or nginx, I don't know) is not interpreting them.

### Source code

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /var/www/example.com/dist/;

    index index.html index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php $uri.html =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    
    error_page 404 404.php;

    ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/cloudflare/cloudflare.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cloudflare/*example.com/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/cloudflare/*example.com/key.pem;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin";
}
```

But nginx is not interpreting the php inside the pages without specifing the extension.

### Example:

`https://example.com/page` is not interpreted and the content type is `application/octet-stream`.

`https://example.com/page.php` is interpreted as it should.

### Logs

The `error.log` file doesn't show any errors

The `access.log` file shows this:

```bash
ip-address - - [18/Sep/2023:17:35:37 +0000] "GET /page HTTP/1.1" 200 7492 "-" "my-user-agent"
```

Comment: So I think routing all traffic through the index.php file on the root will make your life (and loading composer) easier. However in the same [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12931128/5033601) post, they do explain how to do both. Hopefully this helps! 

Comment: (Meta note: we don't use [solved] devices in titles here. A self-answer is welcome, as is marking this as a duplicate. However I think the helpful link from @Richard is not a duplicate as such, just a different way to solve the problem).